# CSS: How to create boxes to act as containers for pictures

Tags: css, image, box

I'm relatively new when it comes to web development but I'm trying to create boxes so they enclose my images. I want it to be divided into 6, something similar to this so that they are neatly formatted:

[image]

Anyone know what's the best way to approach this>? Bootstrap, css? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its very simple layout, you could use bootstrap [columns](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) to achieve this

below is sample layout (make sure you watch this in full page)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="text-center">
   <h2>Image Gallery</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300">
          <div class="caption">
            <p>Lorem ipsum donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
          </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300">
          <div class="caption">
            <p>Lorem ipsum donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
          </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300">
          <div class="caption">
            <p>Lorem ipsum donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
          </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Was without internet for some days... so it's a simple row-column from bootstrap.. Thanks!